# Why won't a value in this bash script equal a command?

Tags: bash

When I run this code, the variable "thing" doesn't change its value to the command. I've tried everything and I just can't get it to work. I want thing to equal something like "1 history cd /bin
history cd /home/user/"

```
#!/bin/bash

val="thing"

function send () {
    thing
    thing=$(history | tail -n 2)
    echo $thing
    echo $val
    # echo $last
    if [ "$val" == *"this"* ]; then
        echo "yes"
    fi
    exit 1
}

send
```

Comment: I think you're running into a very common problem here, which is that it's obvious to *you* want you want, so you think it will be obvious to *us* . . . but, it doesn't work that way. I, for one, have no idea what behavior you're trying to create. Can you explain in more detail? (For example, what are you expecting `echo $thing` to print? What does it actually print?)

Comment: By the way, it seems like a really bad idea to write `exit 1` in this function; that won't just exit the function, it will exit the shell or subshell that's running the function! You probably want `return 1` instead.

Comment: @rualch: While you are basically right, this doesn't make things better here. From the way the whole thing is missing, the OP invokes the whole **script**, not just the function, which is of course nonsense, but it would do the _exit_ anyway after the function has finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder why `$(history | tail -n 2)` returns nothing, it is because history lists commands previously ran in the current shell.

But *your script is a new shell instance*, so it does not carry the history of commands you ran before you execute your script.

If you want that, you have to source the script, not execute it. To source, do:

```
$ . thescript.bash
```

instead of

```
$ ./thescripts.bash
```

instead of this also

```
$ bash thescript.bash
```

---

**Note**: put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see syntax issues.

Comment: Also, history is disabled by default in scripts, so if it's run normally it's not even going to have a list of commands that've run in the script.